# Should I need to renew my US immigrant visa?

Tags: visas, international-travel

I don't know what I need to do for travelling to UK because the law in UK is different from US. I'm asking if I can still travel to UK since that I have only Philippines passport and my US immigrant visa is already expired since 2012. But I am immigrant and a permanent residents in US. I have green card which is still valid and my problem is would i need to renew my Immigrant visa just to visit UK or is there any possible that I can still travel to UK, if I only renew my passport not my Immigrant visa? Would I need to renew both of them so I can visit UK? Or would they let me to enter in UK without/with UK visa? Would they let me to enter in UK with renewing philippine passport and not renewing my Immigrant visa for US? How much the total cost of an immigrant visa fee and passport? Is it alright if i only renew the passport but can i still visit UK without renewing the immigrant visa? what do i need to do?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand. What exactly do you have? It sounds like you have a Philippines passport (is it expired?), a valid US green card (permanent residency), and an expired US immigrant visa (which is fine, since you have a green card). Do you have anything else? And you want to visit the UK for how long and for what purpose?

Comment: So, I want to visit to UK but then my philippines passport is about to expired on June thats why I need to renew my passport this month. Then my US immigrant visa is already expired in 2012. But my green card is still valid. Can I still go in UK to visit my boyfriend? I will be stay there for one month.

Comment: Can I use my philippines passport to visit UK while my US Immigrant visa already expired?

Comment: my purpose is to visit my boyfriend and stay there for one month

Comment: Cause I thought I need to renew my US Immigrant visa just to let me in UK.

Comment: My concern is do i need to renew my US Immigrant visa just to visit my boyfriend who lives in UK. Or I don't need to renew cause I have the green/alien card. and Can I use my philippines passport to visit UK while my US Immigrant visa already expired?

Comment: So, I can visit my boyfriend in UK even my US immigrant visa is already expired cause like what you said its fine if my US immigrant visa is expired cause I have still valid green card.

Comment: yes my philippine passport will be expired. may i ask do you have any experience for travelling to UK?

Comment: Can I travel to UK by using the Philippines passport that will be renew this month and my greencard and US Immigrant visa expired?

Comment: so this is my question, Can i still travel or visit my boyfriend in UK by using the Philippines passport i have that will be renew on this month and the valid green card and the US immigrant visa expired? Would they accept my reason that Im going to visit my boyfriend and im gonna stay there for one month, not six months.?

Comment: Ok I think you've clarified the question more than enough :) I'm sure someone will be along to answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are a permanent resident of the US, but (unless you're stateless) you remain a citizen of the country from which you emigrated, the Philippines, and (unless you're a refugee or stateless) must continue to carry and renew your Philippine passport for travel purposes. If you [naturalize as a US citizen](https://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship/citizenship-through-naturalization/path-us-citizenship), then you can apply for a US passport and use that for travel.

As such, you will need to enter the UK on your existing Philippine passport, and because [you require a UK visa for that visit](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/tourism), you will need to obtain the visa before you travel.

Your US immigrant visa is irrelevant. Its *only* use is for you to travel once to the US and obtain your permanent residence. After you have your green card, the immigrant visa has no other use. In particular, the UK is a completely different country than the US, and a US visa is not valid for *entry* into the UK. The only thing a US immigrant visa may allow you to do in the UK is [transit landside without a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/yes), but your green card is also good for this.

The green card does have *some* travel benefits, though. For instance, you can transit without a visa in some countries that would otherwise require you to obtain an airside transit visa (or in a very few cases, allow landside transit). You can also visit Canada or Mexican border areas without a visa. You should carry both your passport and green card when traveling, to take full advantage of these.

**In short, your immigrant visa has no purpose anymore. You need to renew your *passport* in order to travel. And you need a valid UK visa in order to visit the UK.**

Comment: is there any way to go in UK besides that? Michael

Comment: @A.Macuray You need your valid Philippine passport and a UK Standard Visitor visa. As a US permanent resident, this should not be difficult to get. Or you can wait until you qualify to naturalize as a US citizen and get your US passport. But I reckon that is more than a year from now...

Comment: How can I get the UK standatd visitor visa? @michael

Comment: @A.Macuray Go back up, read the answer, and click the link.

Comment: Did you highlight the link right? Thanks. I just feel bad with that

Comment: how much do you think the cost if i apply for UK visa and how long does it take to get my UK visa?

Comment: @A.Macuray You'll need to carefully read [all the instructions](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) for a UK standard visitor visa. The instructions will tell you the cost, how long it can take, what documents are required, and how to apply. You'll likely want to renew your Philippines passport before you apply for the visa.

Comment: So, my philippines passport is on the process, can I apply for the UK visa?

Comment: @A.Macuray Unless you start reading things much more carefully, then you have no chance of getting a UK visa, and a considerable chance of being scammed. Read Micheal Hampton 's answer carefully. Follow the link about requiring a UK visa. Read all the offical advice and rules on apply for a visitor visa. When it comes to dealing with UK laws and officals, trust what gov.uk (the offical government website) says over anywhere else.

Comment: hint: when you carefully read every page of the official visa instructions, you'll see that you'll need to provide your passport as one of the required documents. You cannot apply for the visa while your passport is off being renewed, because you won't have a passport to give to the UK officials until the renewal is done. In the meantime, you can review the instructions and gather everything you need to apply for the visa, so you're ready to apply when the passport renewal comes back.